# How to check how many doucments available firebase

Tags: database, flutter

How to check how many doucments available in firebase when my query conditions match and i want to print that out

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
    await firestore.collection('stations');

var setNo = collectionReference
    .where('place', isEqualTo: userDistrict.toLowerCase())
    .where('norequest', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 10)
    .snapshots();

var totalEquals = await collectionReference.snapshots().length;
print("documnet afthal :${totalEquals}");

setState(() {
  userLocationSetsNo = totalEquals;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so take this collection example:

```
CollectionReference CollectionRef =
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your-collection-name');
```

after we get its `QuerySnapshot` from Firebase Firestore:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await 
 CollectionRef
        .where('field-name', isEqualTo:'condition')
        .get();
```

we can simply use its `docs` property which will return a `List` containing all collection documents, then get the length of that `List` with the `length` property :

```
print(querySnapshot.docs.length);
```

Hope this helps :)